# Set Volume range in ALSA

Tags: alsa

I just bought a Asus Xonar U3, but it's way too loud. So I played around a little bit and compared values of the Xonar U3 and my old Soundcard in /var/lib/asound.state and noticed there are some values which are different. Specifically I am looking at this block:

```
    control.4 {
            iface MIXER
            name 'PCM Playback Volume'
            value.0 1
            value.1 1
            comment {
                    access 'read write'
                    type INTEGER
                    count 2
                    range '0 - 37'
                    dbmin -3700
                    dbmax 0
                    dbvalue.0 -3600
                    dbvalue.1 -3600
            }
    }
```

Is it somehow possible to change the values range, dbmin and dbmax?

Answer (score 0):

These values *describe* the device. If you change them, you do not change how the device actually behaves.

Comment: Hence the question, HOW to change the values of the device...